# How to enable TypeScript-only Props Typing in Vue3

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

according to the old function rfc, Vue3 will support typescript only props -typing:https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/function-apis/active-rfcs/0000-function-api.md#typescript-only-props-typing

When I tried to following code, it seems not working. Props will be undefined.

```js
interface MessageProps {
  msg: string;
  list: any[];
}
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  setup(props: MessageProps) {
    console.log(props)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As of `vue@3.0.0-beta.14`, the `props` declaration is *still* required despite the RFC indicating it's optional. I don't see any discussion on that particular feature, so I assume it's just not yet implemented.

In the meantime, declaring the `props` shown below would resolve your issue:

```js
export default defineComponent({
  // declaration still required as of vue@3.0.0-beta.14
  props: {
    msg: String,
    list: Array,
  },
  setup(props: MessageProps) { /*...*/ }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I asked this question in Vue discord channel, the core member told me they already opened certain ticket for this issue.